# Add a footer to the thumbnail

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a thumbnail like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="../../IMG/Interface/icon-comun.png" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>...</h3>
            <p><a href="?Menu=C" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And would like to add a footer section inside, like this example: http://bootply.com/67267

Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of thumbnail class

```
<div class="panel-footer">
blah blah blah
</div>
```

css:

```
div.thumbnail{
padding:0px;
}
```